# How do I trigger the server to send an SSE by clicking a button on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server-sent-events

I'm learning about server-sent events and wanted to try my own example. All of the examples I've found set up a server that just uses an interval to send new events to the EventSource on the HTML page. What I'd like to do instead is to have a button on the page that makes a call to the server that will trigger a new event to be sent to the EventSource object.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>

    <div id="click-container">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source = new EventSource('/clicks');
        var clickContainer = document.getElementById("click-container");
        source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
            clickContainer.innerHTML = e.data + '<br>';
        });
    </script>

    <h1>Clicker</h1>

    <button type="button" id="clicker">Click Me</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var btn = document.getElementById("clicker");

        btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    console.log(req.responseText);
                }
            };

            req.open('GET', '/click', true);
            req.send(null);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

But for the server, which I'm doing in Node, I have no idea what to do. I've tried sending the request to the same URL that the EventSource was listening to, but that just resulted in that request getting caught up in the open connection and never completing. I just can't wrap my head around what I need to do, could I please have an explanation of how this should work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a something like Redis as your pub/sub broker. I wrote a two part blog series on how to do this with Node.

1. [Part 1](http://bayn.es/real-time-web-applications-with-server-sent-events-pt-1/)
2. [Part 2](http://bayn.es/real-time-web-apps-with-server-sent-events-pt-2/)

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use `fetch()`

**client.js:**

```js
document.getElementById("clicker").onclick = function() {
  data = { something: "123"}
  fetch("/sendData", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(resp => {
    //do something with returned data
    alert(resp) // { message: "hello" }
  })
}
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post("/sendData", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.something) // "123"

  //return a response to the client side
  res.send({ message: "hello" })
})
```